# SQLite database support

Tags: database

Is there any plan on supporting SQLite someday? It would be very interesting for small instances where we can't create any MySQL or MariaDB databases for example (in my case, free tier hosting coming with the domain name which offers PHP, 30Mb storage but no MySQL database).

Thanks a lot!

Comment: You might be better off asking your question on https://github.com/craftcms/cms/issues, as a feature request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We've looked into it before as I agree, it'd be awesome. But as of February 2020, the answer is no because SQLite is missing some key features that Craft currently relies on: https://www.sqlite.org/omitted.html

Specifically the missing joins and alter table commands.